# Solving Difference Equation using Matlab Neural Toolbox

Tags: matlab, neural-network, differential-equations

I am trying to use Matlab's Neural Network Toolbox to simulate difference equation. The equation is in the form:

> y[k+1] = y[k] + d_t*( -a*y[k] + x[k] )

The **a** and **d_t** are the to be represented by the 2 adjustable weights in the NN. The **a** is the weight in the first layer, the 2nd layer has both weights equal to 1, the 3rd layer (weight without delay) is **d_t**, the last weight is 1.

The network then looks like:
[image]

The code to produce the network is:

```
%% input 
t = 1:100;
x = ones(1,length(t));

%% difference equation
% consntants 
d_t = 0.1;
a = 1;
% initialization
y0 = 0;
% output signal
y = zeros(length(t), 1);
y(1) = y0;

for ii = 1:(length(t)-1)
   y(ii+1) = y(ii) + d_t * (-a*y(ii) + x(ii));
end

% input
plot(t, x, 'b--')
hold on
% difference equation output 
plot(t, y, 'r' )

%% NN
net = network;
% structure
net.numInputs = 1;
net.numLayers = 3;
% neurons
net.inputs{1}.size = 1;
net.layers{1}.size = 1;
net.layers{2}.size = 1;
net.layers{3}.size = 1;

%names
net.inputs{1}.name  = 'x';
net.layers{1}.name  = '1st';
net.layers{2}.name  = '2nd';
net.layers{3}.name  = '3rd';
net.outputs{3}.name = 'y';

% connections
net.biasConnect  = [0; 0; 0]; % exclude biases
net.inputConnect = [0; 1; 0];  % input connected to 2nd layer
net.layerConnect = [0 0 1; ... % 3rd to 1st {1,3}
                    1 0 0; ... % 1st to 2nd
                    0 1 1];    % 2nd to 3rd; 3rd to 3rd
net.outputConnect= [0 0 1];   % 3rd layer connected to output

% set the weights
% input weight
net.IW{2,1} = 1;
net.inputWeights{2,1}.learn = 0;

% 3rd to 1st
net.LW{1,3} = 1; % value
net.layerWeights{1,3}.learn = 0; % do not change

% 1st to 2nd
net.LW{2,1} = -1; % TO BE TRAINED
net.layerWeights{2,1}.learn = 1; % train

% 2nd to 3rd
net.LW{3,2} = 0.1; % delta T (finite time difference)
net.layerWeights{3,2}.learn = 0; % do not change

% 3rd to 3rd
net.LW{3,3} = 1; % value
net.layerWeights{3,3}.learn = 0; % do not change

% add delay
net.layerWeights{1,3}.delays = 1;
net.layerWeights{3,3}.delays = 1;

view(net)

hold on;
plot(net(x),'g--')
```

but the result looks like this:

[image]

It seems like the delays are ignored and the input signal just passes through the constant **d_t**=0.1.

Any idea what is wrong and why the previous output seems to not enter the 1st and 2nd layer ?

Comment: You havent trained the net.

Comment: @AnderBiguri The weights are initialized to reflect the difference equation. So, it is supposed to perform exactly according to difference equation (this is optimal model, it cannot perform any better = no training)

Comment: I see what you are doing, but regarthless of if it works or not: Why? Its the wrong tool. This is not what a NN is nor what it is made for. Why would you want to use a NN to literally implement the same equation you arleady have. It seems right now that you may be completelly missing the point of what a NN is to start with

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thank you for prompt answer. I will go directly to the point. I want to train NN representing a NARX model, Matlab has already BPTT (backpropagation through time) implemented, so I dont need to derive all the lengthy derivations. The first step is to make sure, I can set up NN to behave as NARX (with predefined structure, defined by difference equation). As you may have noticed from the code, only certain parameters will be later trained (I want to check the stability of the training process for different deviations) [edit: ARX, later NARX, the context and problem is the same]

Comment: I think you are using a sledgehammer to open your bean can. Or perhaps a pencil. Just not the right tool. The entire purpose of a NN is not giving it a way of learning the task. If you want to learn a single parameter of an equation, use some other optimization/learning method, such as GAs, or ODEs.

Comment: @AnderBiguri This is somehow misunderstood. The code above is simplified to point out the simplest possible case. ODEs are insufficient for advanced problems. GAs are actually overkill, using global optimum search when only local search is required. Anyway, any idea why the result of the NN is flat-line, when the input is presented ?